# How to make the Chart.js animate when scrolled over?

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to use the pie chart from Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#pieChart-exampleUsage). I have a script which does the job but every time it is reloaded the chart gets bigger and bigger. What do I need to change to fix this?

My code is as follows:

```
var inView = false;
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemBottom >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
if (isScrolledIntoView('#canvas')) {
    if (inView) { return; }
    inView = true;
    new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Pie(data);
} else {
    inView = false;  
}
});
```

Comment: Your code works fine and the chart always has the same size: http://jsfiddle.net/BhsLT/